# Revert to the old value at run time if the certain string is present in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to update my string text column but for some reason it is not updating.I am editing the datagridview at runtime.The user can update the string text except for the case when "do not change" is present in the string.If "do not change" occurs in the string then the user cannot change it or if he does it reverts back to the old value.I want the datagridview to update at runtime.

```
        if (readcontents.contains('do not change')
        {
            this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value = read;
        }
```

Comment: You can handle the RowEditing or RowUpdating event; alternatively, you might look at using Templates to prevent non-editable items from being edited.  I'd look at option 1 first at it might be easier.

Comment: Your problem is to prevent user from editing some cell in some case, you may want to check out the property `DataGridViewCell.ReadOnly`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody is wondering what the answer was..

```
        int row = dataGridView1.RowCount;
        string tr="Do not Change";
        for (int i = 0; i < row-1; i++)
        {
            if(dataGridView1[2,i].Value.ToString().Contains(tr))
            {
                dataGridView1[2, i].ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
```